Using thread for sending mails with smtp
Using SMTP and the Gmail API (Could you please demonstrate both methods?), I need to send thousands of emails, each customized according to a name and containing an attachment. How can I accomplish this process as quickly and efficiently as possible?
My current method, in its simplest form, is as follows:
from os import path
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from traceback import print_exc
from copy import deepcopy
from importlib import util
from time import perf_counter


class EmailSender:
    def __init__(self, username, client, data, message, subject, html, attachments):
        self.username = username
        self.client = client
        self.data = data
        self.message = message
        self.subject = subject
        self.html = html
        self.attachments = attachments

    def send_email(self, index, receivers, message):
        try:

            subject = self.multi_replace(self.subject, {f"${{{key}}}": value for key, value in receivers[2].items()})
            if message.get("subject") is None:
                message["subject"] = subject
            else:
                message.replace_header("subject", subject)

            html_body = self.multi_replace(self.html, {f"${{{key}}}": value for key, value in receivers[2].items()})
            message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, "html"))

            for file, script in self.attachments.items():
                args = [receivers[2][i] for i in script["arguments"]]
                print(args, "--")
                f = call_func(script["script_name"], "main", [file] + args)
                part = MIMEApplication(f[1].read(), Name=f[0])
                part['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{f[0]}"'
                message.attach(part)

            self.client.sendmail(self.username, receivers[0], message.as_string())
        except Exception as e:
            print_exc()

    def prepare_and_send_emails(self):
        for index, i in self.data.items():
            tmp_msg = deepcopy(self.message)

            self.send_email(index, i, tmp_msg)

    @staticmethod
    def multi_replace(string, replacements):
        for old, new in replacements.items():
            string = string.replace(old, new)
        return string

def call_func(script_path, func=None, arguments=None):
    spec = util.spec_from_file_location("module_name", script_path)
    module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    return getattr(module, func)(*arguments)

time = perf_counter()
client = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
client.starttls()
client.login('mail', 'pass')
data = {0: ['xxxx@xxx', [100], {'Name': 'Johan'}], 1: ['xxxx@xxxx', [100], {'Name': 'Max'}],}

message = MIMEMultipart()
subject = "Mail to ${Name}"
html = "Hello Dear ${Name}"
attachments = {'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/A/Kod/Python/Projemsi/mailsender/a.png':
                   {'arguments': [], 'script_name': None},
                'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/A/Kod/Python/Projemsi/mailsender/aa.py':
                    {'arguments': ['Name'],
                    'script_name': 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/A/Kod/Python/Projemsi/mailsender/aa.py'}}
non_script_attachments = [key for key, value in attachments.items() if not value['script_name']]
script_attachments = {key: value for key, value in attachments.items() if value["script_name"]}
for f in non_script_attachments:
    with open(f, "rb") as file:
        part = MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name=path.basename(f))

        part['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{path.basename(f)}"'
        message.attach(part)

sender = EmailSender('makalidap@example.com', client, data, message, subject, html, script_attachments)
sender.prepare_and_send_emails()
print(perf_counter()-time)

But this is so slow. When I use threads like this:
    def prepare_and_send_emails(self):
        threads = []
        for index, i in self.data.items():
            tmp_msg = deepcopy(self.message)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_email, args=(index, i, tmp_msg))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

I encounter various errors. I used similar code within Google, and it gave errors when using threads there too.
When I try open new SMTP server for each thread this is even more slower than normal code.
How can I use something like threads for sending emails?

As an aside, it looks like your email code was written for an older Python version. The email module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new EmailMessage API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from the Python email examples documentation.

The exposition seems to be missing some parts. Are you using the same connection for all the messages, or disconnecting and reconnecting? Probably avoid the latter.

@tripleee I try both of them but original code use same connection. I shared full code.

@triplee I think it is about message content if i solve thread problem i can rewrite this section.
